# Configure Path of MySQL Database on EasyPHP DEVSERVER 16.1.1

Tags: mysql, easyphp

I try to change the default path of DataDir of MySQL installed via EasyPHP DEVSERVER 16.1.1, but every time whene mysql start, it reset the datadir to default value.

Ca u help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following lines in the `eds-app-actions.php` file that is located in the mysql folder you want to use (in `eds-binaries/dbserver`).

```
// Update datadir
//$replacement = '${1}' . str_replace('\\', '/', __DIR__) . '/data/$3'; // original
$replacement = '${1}' . 'your/new/path/$3';
// don't change the other lines

// Update innodb_data_home_dir
//$replacement = '${1}' . str_replace('\\', '/', __DIR__) . '/data/$3'; // original
$replacement = '${1}' . 'your/new/path/$3';
// don't change the other lines

// Update innodb_log_group_home_dir
//$replacement = '${1}' . str_replace('\\', '/', __DIR__) . '/data/$3'; // original
$replacement = '${1}' . 'your/new/path/$3';
// don't change the other lines
```

Comment: I had the same problem with DevServer 17, and this worked for me, thanks to @Oliver. But I'm pretty surprised: sounds like there is a serious inconstency in DevServer???